# typo3 loops or something eats my RAM

Tags: memory-management, typo3

I have an typo3 syte. And after a hack there is somenthing strange. The site is moved on a new server. But when I start the site, then anythig loops or does somethings, that my 4GB ram is used to 100% in 30 seconds. Does anyone has an indea where to look, or how to see where the problem is? Is there any software where I can install to track this. It's a debian linux.

Whne I disable the access to the site with htaccess and allow it only for my IP address, then everything works fine. I can play with the site and the usage of the RAM is ok. I have made som apache benchmarks from my IP address to the homepage and everything ist fine, but when I allow the acccess to the "world", the the server is down in 30 seconds :-(

Thanks for each answer!

Cheers
Nik

Thanks!

Comment: This can be any number of things. If you have moved to a new server then the configuration of that server might be different. Some things might not work as before. Can you post some more specific details? What kind of server are you running on, how big is your database, are you running any large extensions or shops? Do you have any strange requests in your error or access logs?

Comment: Is there any chance you're getting a [dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack? What do you mean by "after a hack", you added something or you were hacked and moved it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP via mod_php of FastCGI?

What is the setting in `TYPO3_LOCAL_CONF['extCache']` (use the install tool to check).

What extensions are you using? Are you sure all your pages can be cached? Sometimes extensions prevent caching if they are set to `USER_INT=1`.

Have you tried benchmarking it using wget? (`wget -r http://yoursite.local`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all You should enable and check Apache logs.

Also it could be mis-configuration of MySQL server.